# GPT Ads - refresh fails when using lazy load

Tags: google-dfp, google-publisher-tag

I'm trying to use the newly introduced `googletag.PubAdsService.enableLazyLoad` option with DFP ads. It works fine during the initial page load, but when I try to refresh ads on the page, I'm getting the following error:

> Exception in queued GPT command TypeError: Cannot read property 'unobserve' of null
>       at Nt (pubads_impl_242.js:1)
>       at pubads_impl_242.js:1
>       at Object._.y (pubads_impl_242.js:1)
>       at Wt (pubads_impl_242.js:1)
>       at pubads_impl_242.js:1
>       at Vt (pubads_impl_242.js:1)
>       at _.V.$a (pubads_impl_242.js:1)
>       at Xu (pubads_impl_242.js:1)
>       at Cv (pubads_impl_242.js:1)
>       at wv._.h.refresh (pubads_impl_242.js:1)

Here is my code:

```
var googletag = googletag || {};
googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
googletag.slots = googletag.slots || {};
var mapping = googletag.sizeMapping()
  .addSize([0, 0], [1000, 1])
  .addSize([320, 0], [[320, 50], [300, 50]])
  .addSize([1025, 0], [970, 90])
  .build();
googletag.slots["push"] = googletag.defineSlot("/1234/sample/", [[970, 90], [320, 50], [300, 50]], "dfp-ad-banner")
  .addService(googletag.pubads())
  .setTargeting("pos", "banner")
  .defineSizeMapping(mapping);
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
  googletag.pubads().enableAsyncRendering();
  googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();
  googletag.pubads().disableInitialLoad();
  googletag.pubads().enableLazyLoad({fetchMarginPercent: 200,renderMarginPercent: 100,mobileScaling: 2.0});
});
googletag.enableServices();
...
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
  googletag.display("dfp-ad-banner");
});
...
googletag.cmd.push(function () {
        // add visibility helper classes
        googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', function (event) {
          var adClass = (event.size[0] > 1 && event.size[1] > 1) ? 'ad-visible' : 'ad-invisible';
          $('#' + event.slot.getSlotElementId()).addClass(adClass);
        });
        // load ads
        googletag.pubads().refresh(null, {changeCorrelator: false});
      });
```

Comment: I've encountered the same, with `refresh()` and `destroy()` causing those errors. Pre-condition is that there's an ad further down the page that hasn't yet been fetched/rendered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is because the `collapseEmptyDivs` so far is not compatible with `enableLazyLoad`. I recommend removing `collapseEmptyDivs`.

Read more about this here https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.PubAdsService_enableLazyLoad

Answer (score 0):

The issue with refresh and destroy should be fixed now. Consider sending feedback from the developer reference page if you run into issues like this in the future.
https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference